# Wordpress 3.9 Database Update Infinite Loop

Tags: updates, upgrade

I recently updated my blog's Wordpress version to 3.9. After running the update I received this message upon trying to access the admin panel.

> Database Update Required
>
> WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to
>   update your database to the newest version.
>
> The update process may take a little while, so please be patient.

I am presented then with a button "**Update Wordpress Database**". When I click the button, after a short pause I am presented with the following message.

> Update Complete
>
> Your WordPress database has been successfully updated!

Great. Except that whenever I try to access the admin panel I am re-presented the first message asking me once again to update my database.

Does anybody know of a way out of this infinite loop?

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had that on one of my sites recently (set to auto update core, so not sure if on 3.9 or one of 3.8.*). Flushing cache fixed it — `wp cache flush` via wp-cli, I imagine other ways would work just as well.

Comment: I can double that. Just had a 3.9 install that just needed several runs and a cache flush to work.

Comment: +1 Flushing the object cache fixes the symptoms of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a missmatch between the databases versions you said you are using in the settings.

Please follow this steps:

1. Go to `/wp-include/` folder and open the `version.php`.
2. Find the value for  `$wp_db_version`, and write it down.
3. Now, open your database, check in the table called `wp_options`
4. Find the `db_version` value:

   `SELECT option_value FROM yourdatabase.wp_options WHERE option_name = 'db_version';`
5. Those two values **must be the same**. Change it in the `version.php` file, not the database.

---

Source: http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/4151
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23506630/2615737