# Plugins Reverting Themself To Older Versions

Tags: plugins

While I'm using a custom theme that has some custom post types, a custom menu declaration, a support thumbnails declaration, and some Gravity Form's customization, whenever I try to update a plugin it updates, then a few page loads later the plugin reverts itself to the version previously installed. In some cases, it even corrupts the plugin and I can't use it anymore.

I have the following plugins installed, ACF, Akismet, and Posts2Posts. Here is the error hat I get with debug set to true

> Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in
>   /wp-content/plugins/one-category-only/oco.php on line 15 Notice:
>   Undefined index: post in /wp-content/plugins/one-category-only/oco.php
>   on line 29 Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query
>   argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see
>   Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
>   in version 3.9.) in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3245

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions for this?

Comment: Is this happening to all plugins or just some. What plugins have you installed and what version of wordpress are you running. Also, what debug info do you get when you enable debug in wp-config

Comment: Maybe this question/answer will help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/141731/32946

Comment: @PieterGoosen ACF, Akismet, and Posts2Posts. Those ones need updating, I'm sure if others needed updating they would do the same thing though. WP_DEBUG: ```Notice: Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in /wp-content/plugins/one-category-only/oco.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: post in /wp-content/plugins/one-category-only/oco.php on line 29

Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.9.) in wp-includes/functions.php on line 3245```

Comment: @Sven No access to CLI on this host I don't think (WPEngine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a simple overlooked issue: we are using WPEngine's Git, and each time we pushed we were pushing our plugins with it. After adding the plugins directory to the .gitignore (the whole wp-content directory, actually) all was well.

Answer (score 1):

This error clearly shows that you have a problem with a plugin called 'one-category-only'. You did not mention this in your question. Uninstall that plugin and see if your problem still exists. I would also suggest that you activate one of the default themes and test your plugins again to see if this solves your problem