# Cannot Update wp DB - Get 500 Error

Tags: wp-admin, updates, wordpress-version, options, automatic-updates

I have this site on godaddy
Failpeep.com , It started giving me this problem yesterday , When I tried to login to admin area , It 1st kept loading if I entered the correct password and took me to a 500 error page after a long wait, If I enter a wrong password it gave me the wrong password message in a second, Then I disabled all the plugins by renaming plugin folder to plugins-old , So I got the w3cache error and blank page, So I created a new plugin folder and moved w3 cache to it so it started showing me all the pages again, 
Now when I try to login to any page , I get this message

> Database Update Required
>
> WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to
>   update your database to the newest version.
>
> The update process may take a little while, so please be patient.
>
> Update WordPress Database

When I click update wordpress database , It keeps loading and then gives me 500 internal error. I had already reverted to default theme as You can see in the site url.

what should I do now , I can not afford to lose the database ,  I tried backing it up from godaddy panel and it is 500mb+ , What should I do :(

Comment: Can you look at your PHP error log and let us know what errors you find in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress 3.9 Database Update Infinite Loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141731/wordpress-3-9-database-update-infinite-loop)

Answer (score -2):

Contact GoDaddy for support. It's their server that's having issues (a 500 error is a server configuration error).

Comment: it could also be a PHP fatal error in a custom plugin

Comment: But why would it return a 500 error? Wouldn't you just get the PHP white screen of death if there's a fatal PHP error? At this point, GoDaddy support needs to be involved as it's their servers returning the error message.

Comment: The 500 is a http reponse code, it doesn't say what happened at the server, which could be a PHP fatal error, and usually is. The answer here is not that it's a job for godaddy, it's that we don't know enough and the OP needs to go and return with more info. Some servers are configured to not show PHP fatals, some show pretty error screens, some show blank white pages

Comment: But if it is godaddy, then we can vote to close the question as off topic, or downvote if we haven't unlocked that ability yet