# Brandoo WordPress Unable to Update to WordPress 4.2.2

Tags: database, updates

I have two Brandoo WordPress sites on Azure. Today I recieved a security alert from Microsoft to update to 4.2.2. However, when I try to update WordPress gets stuck in an infinite loop between two screens. The first screen shows this:

```
Database Update Required
WordPress has been updated!  Before we send you on your way, we have to update your database 
to the newest version. The update process may take a little while, so please be patient. 
[Button - Update WordPress Database]
```

The second screen shows this:

```
Update Complete
Your WordPress database has been successfully updated!
[Button - Continue]
```

I am not able to login to the admin screen for this site, it just keeps cycling between the two screens above. I disabled all plugins before updating. I believe this is a common problem on Azure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress 3.9 Database Update Infinite Loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141731/wordpress-3-9-database-update-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Brandoo isn't (sadly) hosted by Azure at the moment.

This plugin is written to be used by version 3.6. Newer versions make use of queries which will not work on SQL Server.

That's why you get those errors. So, you need to keep your version of wordpress at all costs till a newer version of brandoo is released: https://github.com/Brandoo/Brandoo-WordPress-MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Brandoo WordPress was abandoned. I've now moved to Nami WordPress which is similar. It also works with SQL Server and is more actively developed.